# Multiple Azure Functions Core Tools versions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I have both version v3 and v4 installed of Azure Functions Core Tools on windows.

How do I start a function using a specific version of Azure Functions Core Tools?

When I do like this:

```
c:\code> func start
```

That will start v3.

I can get it to use v4 using hardcoded path:

```
c:\code> c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.10.1\cli_x64\func.exe start
```

But how do I prevent using path that will change from version to version?

Comment: You can set alias for both of "func" exe files via PowerShell.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/d04n3kg.png - I didn't get how to run specific function using version path or version based. I have tried running func by going to v4, it asked me that there is no local.settigns.json or host.json. so i have copied my timer trigger project's host and local settings json file into azure function core tools version path and tried running function like func.exe start but I didn't get any output

Comment: Instead, I got few errors. But I don't understand like what is the purpose of running the functions from version based, and you cannot maintain two versions of azure function core tools in the same device like if you install azure function core tools version 4 by assuming you have v3 previously, if you check the version after installing new, it will give newly installed version.

Comment: I mean every new version comes with few bug fixes and efficient performance. Could you please clarify me the purpose of running the functions from specific version based azure function core tools? So that, I'll try in any other possible ways!

Comment: I ended up uninstalling v3 and only having v4 installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad that your issue got resolved based on my comments I am converting that as an answer to help the other community members who face similar kind of issues.

- You can only install one version of core tools on a given computer as stated in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v3,windows,csharp,portal,bash,keda#v2).
- When you check the version of azure function core tools, it will show the version you have installed recently.
- After installing new version of core tools to run the old version project,

  - Either you have to update the azure functions core tools package
    version inside the project (or)
  - Downgrade/Upgrade your azure    functions core tools version according to your requirement and compatibility in your local environment.

Comment: What's the suggested path for a mix of function apps across version of .NET? If we have several functions built on 3.1 and want to start building on 6.0, can this be done on the same machine without having to constantly swap the installed version of core tools?

Comment: @ShawnHubbard, No need to swap the installed version of core tools. If you install VS200, while selecting the .Net Version, it will also shows you which azure function core tools version supports version of .Net like 1) https://i.imgur.com/Ech9fyT.png 2) https://i.imgur.com/JL5zYyA.png 3)https://i.imgur.com/iJuU81i.png

Comment: What I want to solve for is the situation where we have a suite of functions - some written in 3.1 and some being written in 6.0. If we continue moving forward with 6.0, it looks like we'll have to swap between installing v3 and v4 until everything is migrated to 6.0 and we stay with v4. Do I have that right or am I missing something?

Comment: @ShawnHubbard, You have the right way, as I have a few function codes in 3.1 and a few in 6.0. I'm running both of them and working well, but not swapped. When 3.1 / 6.0 function app is running, VS/Vs Code takes the right version of AZ Function Core tools automatically, no swapping is required! If any glitch, it asks you to upgrade!

Comment: I see. It looks like the issue in my case is a dependency on Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage. Version 3.0.10 doesn't seem to run on Core Tools v4. You're correct that if I just do a new function on Tools v3 and install v4, things work fine. We'll still need to do some refactoring, but this is a bit more encouraging.

Answer (score 4):

If running on Mac and installed the function core tools V3 *and* V4 using Homebrew, you can easily switch between installed versions.

Just run this command to switch to V3:
brew unlink azure-functions-core-tools@3 && brew link --overwrite azure-functions-core-tools@3

To switch to V4, use the same command but with a trailing @4, like this:
brew unlink azure-functions-core-tools@4 && brew link --overwrite azure-functions-core-tools@4